# Underscore nested templating with same context

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I want to use nested templates in underscoreJS, and access the same variables in the same way between parent and children templates.

```
//Backbone :
this.model = new Backbone.model.extend({backgroundColor:red});
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes);

//Underscore template:
<%=backgroundColor%>
<%=subTemplate()%>

//Underscore subtemplate:
<%=backgroundColor%>
```

JAshkenas approach is to put the model in another object like stated [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/231)

```
//Backbone :
this.$el.html({model : this.model.attributes});

//But that means accessing "model" for every property, and having to pass "model" to each subtemplate
<%=model.backgroundColor%>
<%=subTemplate({model:model})%>
```

Is there a cleaner/shorter solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, we can give the nested template the same context by passing `obj` to it.

```
//Backbone:
this.model = new Backbone.model.extend({backgroundColor:red});
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes);

//Underscore template:
<%= backgroundColor %>
<%= subTemplate(obj) %>

//Underscore subtemplate:
<%= backgroundColor %>
```

Looking into the [annotated source for underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-172), When no `settings.variable` is given, the code results in the following at the top of every underscore template:

```
function anonymous(obj,_) {
    var __t,__p='',__j=Array.prototype.join,print=function(){__p+=__j.call(arguments,'');};
    with(obj||{}){
        /* your template */
    }
    return __p;
}
```

Comment: I was also struggling with this until I noticed the generated template function while debugging in Chrome, then confirmed it by looking into underscore's annotated source.

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach which is nice :

```
//Backbone Render
this.$el.html(this.template.call(this.model.attributes, this.model.attributes));

//Underscore template
<%=backgroundColor%>
<%=subTemplate.call(this, this)%>

//Subtemplate
<%=backgroundColor%>
```